# How do I run my code when device is connected by usb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

I have written a program in node.js that lets me interact with certain usb connected device. It works fine when running the program explicitly. However, I was wondering if there is any way (I suppose there is) to automate the process of running this program when the device is connected.
I am operating on a macOs High Sierra btw, as I've seen similar questions but for different operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. AutoRun has been disabled for a variety of security reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/410590/5203655

> You can't. Autostarting applications is impossible under Mac OS X.